# Jupyter notebook kernel keeps restarting the moment I open a notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, python-3.7

The server starts but the moment I open a notebook, even a blank one, the kernel die and keeps restarting. I'm using python3.7 in arch-linux.
The error "RuntimeError: This event loop is already running" keeps happening in loop.

```html
Connecting to: tcp://127.0.0.1:36789
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 658, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 477, in start
    ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 132, in start
    self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 510, in run_forever
    raise RuntimeError('This event loop is already running')
RuntimeError: This event loop is already running
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably an Arch Linux issue, that has been asked on their forums multiple times, e.g. [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=239356), and a [bug report](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/59535) has been created. It should be solved once python-ipykernel is upgraded, but I have no idea how long that'll take.

UPDATE: it has been updated in the repo, so upgrading your system will fix it.

<s>A temporary hacky solution that worked for me is to upgrade it using pip as a user (so it gets installed in ~/.local instead of /usr/), i.e.:</s>

```
pip install --user --upgrade ipykernel
```

This way, you don't have to downgrade any packages (which might be a better solution but more annoying to do).
When the Arch team has upgraded the package it is probably a good idea to remove the pip-version (`pip uninstall ipykernel`)